# Constrained model demonstrates slightly better fit than the unconstrained model (Measurment invariance). Explanation?

Tags: confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am currently examining measurement invariance in lavaan. I create my unconstrained model. Then I apply constrains to loadings and loadings+intercepts. I use the WLSMV estimator. The following pattern in the results is replicated with the DWLS estimator without mean and variance adjusted. (ordered=TRUE argument in one case and estimator="DWLS" in another)

```
# Unconstrained model

m1<-'
       S=~S1+S2+S3+S4+S5+S6
       P=~P1+P2+P3+P4+P5+P6
       C=~C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6
                                        
       '

m1.fit<-cfa(m1,data=Phase2,estimator="WLSMV", 
                                   group="Gender", meanstructure=TRUE, std.lv=TRUE)

summary(m1.fit,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE)


# Constrained model (Metric)

m2<-'
       S=~S1+S2+S3+S4+S5+S6
       P=~P1+P2+P3+P4+P5+P6
       C=~C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6
                                        
       '

m2.fit<-cfa(m2,data=Phase2,estimator="WLSMV", 
                                        group="Gender", group.equal=c("loadings"), 
                                        meanstructure=TRUE, std.lv=TRUE)

summary(m2.fit,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE)

# Constrained model (Scalar)

m3<-'
       S=~S1+S2+S3+S4+S5+S6
       P=~P1+P2+P3+P4+P5+P6
       C=~C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6
                                        
      '

m3.fit<-cfa(m3,data=Phase2,estimator="WLSMV", 
                                        group="Gender", group.equal=c("loadings","intercepts"), 
                                        meanstructure=TRUE, std.lv=TRUE)

summary(m3.fit,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE)

# Compare MI models

ComMI=compareFit(m1.fit,m2.fit,m3.fit)


summary(ComMI)
```

Unscaled chi-square test statistics follow a logical pattern with m1 having the lowest and m3 the highest. (m1 = 181.64, m2 = 239.28, m3 = 259.97)

Scaled chi-square test statistics on the other hand show that the loading-constrained model (m2) has better fit. (m1 = 394.881, m2 = 380.839†, m3 = 408.288).

The same pattern is followed by scaled fit indices. CFI for example is: m1 = .954, m2 = .965†, m3 = .960.). Scaled RMSEA follows the same pattern. Scaled SRMR is the only one that demonstrates best fit for the unconstrained model.

Unscalled fit indices are not helpful because they show perfect fit and are the same for all models.

What is a plausible explanation for this? I thought that by definition constrained models should evidence worse fit.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Scaled chi-square test statistics on the other hand show that the constrained model (m2) has better fit

You cannot make that judgement by comparing the scaled $\chi^2$ statistics from different models.  A model's $\chi^2$ is already a model comparison of the fitted/hypothesized model to a saturated model ($df=0$, usually specified by simply estimating all (co)variances, etc.).

When using least-squares estimators for categorical data, any test statistic comparing 2 models must be corrected to more closely/approximately follow a $\chi^2$ distribution.  You do not compare different restricted/hypothesized models (e.g., different levels of invariance) by comparing their corrected statistics that compare each of those models to a saturated model.  You compare the models directly, then correct that test statistic.  This is what the `compareFit()` function returns in the `@nested` slot, which is simply the saved `anova()` output (see also the `?lavTestLRT` help page, which is the function called by `anova()` for `class?lavaan` objects).

> The same pattern is followed by scaled fit indices

Fit indices don't necessarily follow your expectation even without corrected statistics.  Many of them adjust by *df*, so CFI for a more-restricted model will nonetheless increase (and RMSEA decrease) when $\Delta \chi^2 < \Delta df$.

> I thought that by definition constrained models should evidence worse fit

It depends what you mean by "fit".  A test statistic is based on assumptions (e.g., the $H_0$ model is (equivalent to) the correct model), as do the scale and shift parameters used to correct a test statistic.  Uncorrected statistics will still follow the order you expect for nested models, but the *p* values are incorrect when the (null-)hypothesized model is *not* a good fit to the data.  Corrected statistics can give unexpected ordering because the scale/shift parameter(s) might be inconsistent across the models being compared, due to the $H_0$ model not fitting well.

Comment: That was a very helpful answer. Thank you! 

Following on your CFI comment: If when **Δχ2 < Δdf**, **CFI** increases in a more restricted model, then the idea of ΔGOF and the usual proposed cutoffs that accompany chi square difference tests in measurement invariance testing should not apply globally, right? I am asking because I see widespread use of changes in CFI in the evaluation of measurment invariance even without taking into account chi-square difference testing, and now following your explanation, this seems kind of off.

Comment: Good intuition.  I agree that the widespread use of ΔGOFs is "way off", as that is not what GOFs were designed to do.  But there are ways to define GOFs specifically for the purpose of model comparison.  Here is a recently accepted preprint showing how to compute RMSEA for nested-model comparisons (with some limited discussion on CFI): https://doi.org/10.31234/osf.io/wprg8

Comment: Thanks again! Reading it rn. Have a great day!